# Postfix smarthost sends as root

Tags: email, postfix

I have a Debian 8 test server that has only root. I have configured it to send emails with https://wiki.amahi.org/index.php/Gmail_As_Relay_On_Ubuntu by making use of a new gmail account eg atuxxxxx6@gmail.com.

That email has as name atux t. The thing is that when I send emails from the Debian box it only appears as: root

How do i get rid of the root and make it appear with the name I want?

Comment: Set `From: atux123456@gmail.com` in the header of the email. This will depend on how you are sending the email. Postfix doesn't have anything to do with that.

Comment: where is that field?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the table 'generic', provided by postfix to re-write both envolope (smtp) -addresses and mail header addresses.

Do that by

a) put the address-rewrite rule in a file called /etc/postfix/generic

```
root@your-domain.com someone@anotherdomain.com
root someone@anotherdomain.com
```

Postfix then rewrites the two matches above to the someone.. - addresses.

b) create a postfix compatible map out of it:

postmap /etc/postfix/generic

c) activate the map in '/etc/postfix/main.cf'

```
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

d) reload config for postfix

```
postfix reload
```

Then you should watch the mail-log. Be careful: rewritten addresses are of course subject to spamchecks on the receivers side  ...